# Sending Multiple Nested NameValue Arrays in Android MultipartMode POST

Tags: java, android, arrays, http-post

Question: How do you send embedded associative (name => value) sub-arrays on a multipart http POST, instead of just the ordinary single dimensional, top level name => value pairs? I searched far and long and was not able to find an example of this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should not post an answer as question. It would make more sense if you state your original problem as a question and then post your solution as an answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks for the protocol correction. I'll try and circle back and reformat my post to conform to the Question then Answer posting format. -SM

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to this problem: How to send sub-arrays of name => value pairs on a multipart post from an Android device using a MultipartEntityBuilder entity. This is what worked for me. It also sends an image file, but examples of that abound, what's unique here is the embedded, nested associative arrays on the same post request. I hope this helps someone else. If you see problems, please feel free to point them out. Please pardon any formatting faux pas, as this is my first posting here. Thanks, Scott

```
public String makePostRequest() {

    public final static String INTENT_URL_PARAM = "server_url";
    public final static String INTENT_API_PARAM = "server_api";
    // Note: extras array is the incoming intent bundle, btw.
    String url = extras.getString(INTENT_URL_PARAM);
    String api = extras.getString(INTENT_API_PARAM);
    url += "api/" + api; // add the api call to the base URL

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  

    String filePath = extras.getString("file_path");
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + "file failed exists(); filePath = " + filePath);
    } 
    else {
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ": try {putting together multipart post request}");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            // add image file
            builder.addPart("file", fileBody);
            // add additional post data
            builder.addTextBody("user_id", extras.getString("user_id"));
            // assemble the item[] and item_media[] array.
            builder.addTextBody("item[name]", extras.getString("name"));
            builder.addTextBody("item[description]", extras.getString("description"));
            builder.addTextBody("item[item_type]", extras.getString("item_type"));
            builder.addTextBody("item[units]", extras.getString("units"));
            builder.addTextBody("item_media[url]", extras.getString("item_url")); 
            builder.addTextBody("item_media[mime_type]", extras.getString("mime_type"));
            builder.addTextBody("item_media[encoding]", extras.getString("encoding"));
            if (extras.containsKey("hasGeoTag") && extras.getString("hasGeoTag").contentEquals("true") ) {
                // add geotag name => value data
                builder.addTextBody("geolocation[lon]", extras.getString("lon"));
                builder.addTextBody("geolocation[lat]", extras.getString("lat"));
                builder.addTextBody("geolocation[ele]", extras.getString("ele"));
            }

            httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseTmp = response.toString();

            entity.consumeContent();
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 

            return responseTmp; // dumb string response for code sample. Use something more fitting yourself.
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i (TAG, "Http Post Failed. ClientProtocolException Exception: " );
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i (TAG, "Http Post Failed. IOException Exception: " );
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return "Some error string as you see fit.";
}
```

The www server received this request data in the following format (as printed with php print_r($_POST,true))

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 98
    [item] => Array
        (
            [name] => Profile Image
            [description] => image for user profile
            [item_type] => 1
            [units] => images
        )

    [item_media] => Array
        (
            [url] => null
            [mime_type] => image/png
            [encoding] => null
        )

    [geolocation] => Array
        (
            [lon] => -133.03752347
            [lat] => 23.8897191
            [ele] => 229.89999389648438
        )

)
```